# Batch insert with Spring Integration JDBC

Tags: spring-integration

I am new to Spring Integration. I followed few documents and made my SI jdbc work. Now I am trying to see if we can do multiple inserts at the same time with SI jdbc.

To implement single insert, I did the following:

1. Interface with a method having parameter of my data object
2. SI xml with
   a. channel
   b. gateway(interface details)
   c. outbound gateway - db and query details
   d. bean with key and value pairs for payload mapping

Can anyone explain how to do a basic bulk insert with SI jdbc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a functionality isn't supported yet: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3364. We still hope to fix it in current `5.0` iteration and contribution is always welcome.

What I can suggest as a workaround it to use `JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate()` directly from some service method and use `<service-activator>` to call that method instead of `<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter>`.